# Is there a way in Java to create an array in a range in one line?

Tags: java, arrays, range

I have arrays like this that are within a range:

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int[] arr2 = {7,8,9,10,11};
int[] arr3 = {12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

Is there a one-line way to create these lists (possibly using a range function) similar to Python like this:

```
arr = list(range(1, 7))
```

Comment: With Java 8, you can do `IntStream.range(1, 7)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-):

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive).toArray();
```

or [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-):

```
int[] result = IntStream.rangeClosed(startInclusive, endInclusive).toArray();
```

Comment: Is there a way without using IntStream,or importing? just wondering.

Comment: @karamazovbros if you want to shorten it then you need to add the import `import static java.util.stream.IntStream.*;` which you can then do `int[] ints = range(startInclusive, endInclusive).toArray();`

Comment: That's good to know as well, but what I meant as not importing IntStream at all, like an alternative way without importing.

Comment: you have to import a package in order to use things that are contained in it... this is not necessarily specific to `IntStream` even for lists you need to import for example `import java.util.List;` in order to use it. @karamazovbros

Comment: Yes, I know this. I guess I was wondering if there was something like list comprehension in Python that's just built-in without importing anything else.

Comment: @Aomine you don't have to import it: `int[] result = java.util.stream.IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive).toArray();` would work.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, you're right I guess. I can't remember when I _had to_ use that approach as importing just makes things a lot easier and more readable.